# Google not crawling links in AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, googlebot

I have an AngularJS application that is injected into 3rd party sites. It injects dynamic content into a div on the 3rd party page. Google is successfully indexing this dynamic content but does not appear to be crawling links within the dynamic content. The links would look something like this in the dynamic content:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/support?title=Example Title&titleId=12345">Link Here</a>
```

I'm using query parameters for the links rather than an actual url structure like:

```
http://www.example.com/support/title/Example Title/titleId/12345
```

I have to use the query parameters as I don't want the 3rd party site to have to change their web server configuration to redirect unfound URLs.

When the link is clicked I use the $locationService to update the url in the browser and then my angular application responds accordingly. Mainly it shows just the relevant content based on the query params, sets the page title and meta description.

Many of the articles I have read use the route provider in angularJS and templates but I'm not sure why this would make a difference to the crawler?

I have read that google should view urls with query parameters as separate pages so I don't believe that should be the issue:
https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html

The only things I have not tried are 1. providing a sitemap with the urls that have the query parameters and 2. adding static links from other pages to the dynamic links to help google discover those pages.

Any help, ideas or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: should be uri encoding spaces in your url

Comment: Yes, they get encoded, just didn't encode them in my example

Comment: how do you know they aren't crawling them and how long have these links been active? And do sites they are have reasonable traffic?

Comment: And if you use `$locationService` to switch are these url's able to be found in `<a>` tags?

Comment: I know the links aren't followed because I have made changes to content and I see that content get indexed but the links are not crawled, I can confirm by checking web server logs (there is an AJAX request when link is hit). One site has reasonable traffic 400-600k unique visitors a month. The site I directly control does not have good traffic but I've used fetch & render on google web master tools and asked it to crawl links. Yes the urls the $locationService sets are in the <a> tags.

Comment: Try to read this https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more

Answer (score 1):

This happens because google crawlers are not able to get the static html from your url since your pages are dynamically rendered with Javascript, you can achieve what you want using the following :

Since `#!` is deprecated, You can tell google that your pages are rendered with javascript by using the following tag in your header

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

On finding the above tag google bots will request your urls with the `_escaped_fragment_` query parameter from your server like

```
http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/support?title=Example Title&titleId=12345
```

Then you need to rebuild your original url from the _escaped_fragment_ on your server and it will look like this again

```
http://www.example.com/support?title=Example Title&titleId=12345
```

Then you will need to serve the static HTML to the crawler for that url.
You can do that using a headless browser to access the url. `Phantom.js` is a good option to render your page using the javascript and then give the contents into a file to create a HTML snapshot of your page. You can save the snapshot as well on your server for further crawling, so when google bots visit can you can directly serve the snapshot instead of re-rendering the page again.

Answer (score 0):

The web crawler might be running at a higher priority than the AngularJS interpretation of your dynamic links as the web crawler loads the page. Using [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) makes the dynamic link interpretation happen at a higher priority. Hope it works!

Comment: I haven't heard of trying the ng-href, I will try this. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

> If you use urls with #
>   Nothing after the hash in the url gets sent to your server. Since Javascript frameworks originally used the hash as a routing mechanism, that's a main reason why Google created this protocol.

Change your urls to #! instead of just using #.

> angular.module('myApp').config([
>       '$locationProvider',
>       function($locationProvider) {
>           $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
>       }
>   ]);

Comment: I'm not using # in the URL, and I'm pretty sure #! has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

This is how **Google** and **bing** handle the ajax calls.

> The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) is mentioned here.

The overview as mentioned in the docs is as follows

> The **crawler** finds a pretty **AJAX URL** (*that is, a URL containing a #! hash fragment*). It then requests the content for this URL from your **server** in a slightly modified form. Your web server returns the content in the form of an HTML snapshot, which is then **processed by the crawler**. The **search results** will show the **original URL**.

Step by Step guide is shown in the docs.

> Since the **Angular JS** is designed for the **Client Side** so you will need to configure your **Web server** to summon a **headless html browser** to access your web page and deliver a **hashbang url** which will be given to the **special google URL**.
>
> If you use **hashbang URL** then you would need to instruct the **angular** **application** to use them instead of **regular hash values**

```
 App.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routes, $location) {

    $location.hashPrefix('!');

    $routes.when('/home',{
      controller : 'IndexCtrl',
      templateUrl : './pages/index.html'
});
```

as mentioned in the code example [here](https://github.com/yearofmoo-articles/AngularJS-SEO-Article/blob/master/js/application.js#L54)

> However if you do not wish to use **hashtag url** but still inform the google of the **html content** but still want to inform the google then you can use this **meta tag** as [this](https://github.com/yearofmoo-articles/AngularJS-SEO-Article/blob/master/index.html#L6)

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!" />
```

> and then configure the angular to use the htmlURL's

```
 angular.module('HTML5ModeURLs', []).config(['$routeProvider', function($route) {
  $route.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

and then whichever method to be installed via module

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['HashBangURLs']);
//or
var App = angular.module('App', ['HTML5ModeURLs']);
```

Now you will need a **headless browser** to **access the url**
You can use `phantom.js` to download the contents of the page ,run the `javascript` and then give the contents into a temporary file.

[Phantomrunner.js](https://github.com/yearofmoo-articles/AngularJS-SEO-Article/blob/master/.phantomjs-runner.js) which takes any url as input,downloads and parses the html into DOM and then checks the data status.

Test each page by using the function defined [here](https://github.com/yearofmoo-articles/AngularJS-SEO-Article/blob/master/test/spec/pages_spec.js)

> SiteMap can also be made as well as shown in this [example](https://github.com/yearofmoo-articles/AngularJS-SEO-Article/blob/master/sitemap.xml)

The best feature is you can use search console of verify your site url using

> **[Google search console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en)**
>
> ***Full attribution goes to the website and the author mentioned in this [site](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html)***

.

> **UPDATE 1**

Your crawler needs the pages as -

```
- com/
- com/category/
- com/category/page/
```

By default, however, Angular sets your pages up as such:

```
- com
- com/#/category
- com/#/page
```

**Approach 1**

**Hash bang** allows Angular to know which *HTML elements to inject with JS* which can be done as mentioned before but since it has been *depericated* hence the another solution would be the following

> Configure the `$locationProvider` and set up the base for relative links

- You can use the `$locationProvider` as mentioned in these [docs](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag) and set the **html5mode to true**

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

This lets Angular change the routing and URLs of our pages without refreshing the page

- Set the base and head of your document as `<base href="/">`

> The $location service will automatically fallback to the hashbang method for browsers that do not support the HTML5 History API.
>
> Full attribution goes to the [page](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag) and the [author](https://pub.scotch.io/@chris)

Also to mention there are also some other measures and tests that you can take care of as mentioned in this [document](https://www.deepcrawl.com/knowledge/best-practice/angular-js-and-seo/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the #! url scheme is deprecated, it even says so on the official documentation link you referenced.

Comment: yea in your question you mentioned the googlebot tag so i thought this might be the optimum solution.It is also mentioned in the documentation that crawling through the googlebot has been disallowed.As long as you dont block the google bot,you can render your web pages like mordern browsers.Ive also added the search console where you can check whether your url can be fetched or not.

Comment: i've updated my question as to why angular app dis not able to crawl google urls,so maybe you can provide me with some feedback